# Passing a SSRS parameter, but no records shows in my report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have one dataset has "YES" and "NO" as value
And I have created a parameter and set my dataset `WHERE COMPLETED IN (@Parameter)`
and set `allow multiple values` in my parameter
however, when i open my report, i dont see any of the records, and the drop down filter does not work at all

By default, i want to have both options and user allow to change yes or no or both
How do i fix this?
Please let me know if my question is vague i can add more details

Comment: When you have a parameter that allows multiple values it will actually pass through a comma-delimited string - eg. "0,1" - not the individual values that you're thinking you're getting.  So you need to factor that into your SQL query - easiest way is to use the "string_split" function (if you're running a compatible version of SQL), otherwise find something similar for an older version of SQL

Comment: @Craig, if the dataset query is a SQL statement (not calling an SP) then the OP's method should be OK. I guess the problem is populating the parameter values in the first place.

Comment: check the parameter values exactly match the column values in your database. It's the parameter's `.Value` that gets passed, not the `.Label`

Comment: YES and No actually come from a CASE WHEN statement.   not sure if this the problems

Comment: It sounds like it should work. Are you sure the cases are the same? `YES <> Yes` if your db is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your @Parameter value will actually just contain a single string (assuming you're using JOIN to pass the combined parameter values).

SQL Server's STRING_SPLIT() function will do the trick for you - although it's only compatible with certain SQL versions (but you can find similar functions online that support earlier versions of SQL).

For example:
@Parameter ends up being populated with a string of "0,1" - ie. both Yes and No

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE COMPLETED IN
(
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Parameter, ',')
);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for responding. but i got this error msg: "procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified"    one more thing i want to address, i have another parameter that using the same format but work perfectly."IN(@parameter) Btw, for this one, i have a CASE WHEN function  contiditon -> "YES" THEN "NO"    not sure if this will impact